# Feature selection without class labels column

Tags: python, machine-learning, feature-selection

I want to perform feature selection on the list of 52 features that I have.
But I do not have the class label column in my dataset.
So how do I select features without dependency on class label.

For example: Select K Best algorithm chooses features based on relationship between features and the class labels. As said in my case I do not have class labels column itself

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for feature selection for unsupervised learning. Some common methods: Removing low-variance features (an implementation [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.VarianceThreshold.html)). Removing correlated features (can be implemented using `corr()` from [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html)). Performing Principal Feature Analysis (PFA) (a python implementation [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/108743/methods-in-r-or-python-to-perform-feature-selection-in-unsupervised-learning)). More advanced methods can be found in *Feature Selection for Clustering* section of this [book](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.295.8115&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

There is also [PCA](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html), which is not feature selection, but extraction, but useful if the ultimate goal is dimensionality reduction.